# CHAR_LENGTH for every cell in a table

Tags: mysql, function

I'm wondering if I can use the MySQL function Char_length for every cell in a table without do a loop for every row.

Sample code:

```
select char_length(employee_id) from employees;
```

That returns:

```
- char_length(employee_id)
---------------------------
3
5
4
...
```

How can I do a char_length for everything in the table?

I'm looking for a table char_length without knowing the columns.

Answer (score 1):

you can select multiple things at a time in select statements.

```
select char_length(employee_id), char_length(column2), ... from employees;
```

Comment: I'm looking for a table char_lenght without knowing the columns.